# UICollectionViewCell with different size when rotate the device

Tags: ios, swift, containers, uicollectionviewcell

Good evening.

First I have a SplitViewController.

In the Detail I have a segmentController with two segment items ( ScreenOne, ScreenTwo).

ScreenOne = TableViewController

ScreenTwo = CollectionViewController

I put a container in the detail and this container can be a table or a collection depending on the selected segment.

The problem is that the method `collectionView(_, layout: , sizeForItemAt:)` don't make the right calculation when I rotate the device to portrait and when I rotate back to landscpae.

"I use the width of the screen to make the calculation"

At the beginning I think that the problem was that when I get the size of the view it doesn't count the size of the master. Because I use a container and a viewController separate I wondered that the view doesn't know about the splitView.

If you have some doubt pleas contact me.

I'm thankfull for any and all help.

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class StudentsGroupCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    ///The sizes for the insets of the collection view
    fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30)

    ///The amount of columns displayed per row in the collection view
    fileprivate let numColumns: Int = 3

    ///Reference to the size of the cells
    fileprivate var cellSize: CGSize!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let parent = parent {
            cellSize = collectionView?.calculateCellSizeWith(sectionInsets: sectionInsets, numColumns: numColumns, and: parent.view.frame.width)
        }

        print("The cellSize at the beggining: \(cellSize) - \(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? "Por" : "Lan")")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 9
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel

        label.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return cell
    }

}



extension StudentsGroupCollectionViewController: 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //TO DO: Cell size with different at rotation device

        return cellSize
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionInsets.bottom
    }


    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        cellSize = collectionView?.calculateCellSizeWith(sectionInsets: sectionInsets, numColumns: numColumns, and: size.width)

        print("The cellSize at the transition: \(cellSize) - \(UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait ? "Por" : "Lan")")

        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

}
```

I think that the main methods here are the viewWillApper and the last viewWillTransiontion(to size:)

The way I want
[image]Good afternoon.

The way it is
[image]

Comment: In the viewWillApper(_:) I call set size of the cells to be 1/3(one third) of the screen width. And when The user rotate the screen I make the same calculation. @creeperspeak

Comment: @creeperspeak I put the code and if you see some error pleas tell me and I will fix and any doubt you can ask.

Comment: A couple things - I assume your `calculateCellSize` function just takes the width passed in, subtracts `insets.left` and `insets.right`, and then divides by the number of columns?  What about the interitem spacing?  That's the thing that looks wrong in the bottom screenshot, and I notice that you don't have that layout delegate method in your pasted code.

Comment: Actually I think I just realized what it probably is - your `reloadData` all is being called inside `willTransition`, with "will" being the keyword.  It means your collectionView is being reloaded before the screen size finishes its transition.  You can put that reload function inside the transition coordinator's `notifyWhenInteractionEnds` completion handler and maybe that'd solve it.